# How to intercept a smart RTH request and cancel it?

Tags: ios, dji-sdk, drone.io

I want to enable smart RTH, but instead of allowing the aircraft to execute that action, I want to plan my own mission home. Is this possible by using `DJIFlightControllerParamConfirmSmartReturnToHomeRequest`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smart RTH is a complete package. You can't cherry pick parts of it and replace them.

What you can do is create your own return to home missions and trigger them from your mobile app (MSDK/UXSDK) or onboard app (OSDK).

Then you can trigger it using a button in the app, or map it to C1/C2 buttons even.

To give a more detailed answer, I would need more details on your question.

Comment: I want to maximize my flight time, but ensure when that minimum battery threshold needed for the aircraft to come back home safely and land is met (from the aircraft's current position), that I’m able to stop the timeline, build a new mission and upload that mission for the aircraft to come home (its a custom mission with some custom settings).